# Dynamically resize a Bootstrap UI modal when DIV expanded/collapsed

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following Bootstrap UI modal template that displays a list of customers in a scrolling DIV.

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Select a customer</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-container">
            <label data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
                <input name="customer" type="radio" data-ng-value="{{cust}}" value="{{cust}}" data-ng-checked="{{cust}}.name==$parent.selected.item.name" ng-model="$parent.selected.item" />{{cust.name}}<span class="text-muted">&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{cust.address}}</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-left" data-ng-click="new()">New</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        <div id="newCustomer" class="collapse">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="customerName" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input id="customerName" class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" placeholder="New customer name" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="customerAddress" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input id="customerAddress" class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.address" placeholder="New customer address" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are three buttons at the bottom `New`, `OK` and `Cancel`.  What I want to happen is when the `New` button is clicked, the `newCustomer` `div` block should be toggled between expanded and collapsed states and importantly to resize the modal so that when expanded the modal will resize to fit the space taken up by the `div` block, and also to shrink the modal when the `div` block is collapsed.

Can this be done using a pure Bootstrap and AngularJS solution?

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.1 and AngularJS v1.3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is to actually use [bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) within your modal. This way you'd have everything done with boostrap.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
            <input name="customer" type="radio" data-ng-value="{{cust}}" value="{{cust}}" data-ng-checked="{{cust}}.name==$parent.selected.item.name" ng-model="$parent.selected.item" />{{cust.name}}<span class="text-muted">&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{cust.address}}</span>
        </label>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="customerName" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Customer Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
         <input id="customerName" class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" placeholder="New customer name" />
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="customerAddress" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
           <input id="customerAddress" class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.address" placeholder="New customer address" />
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  NEW BUTTON
</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tea6gj4e/1/

Comment: Just tried that and nothing is happening when I click the button.

Comment: What do you mean? Where did you put that button?

Comment: If you look at the source I posted in the OP you can see where I have put the `New` button -- it's in the modal footer.

Comment: yes of course you had to put that in your footer, it was just an example. See my updated answer

Comment: I have used your example and the modal doesn't display at all. I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.1 and Bootstrap UI with templates v0.12.0.

Comment: hey man, the modal is copied from bootstrap itself. But the important thing anyway isn't the modal but the added collapse bit with your stuff in and the button NEW as you're asking. So copy those parts and place them in your modal and see what happens

Comment: I have updated my answer with a full working code and a jsfiddle example for you

Comment: Excellent that looks just the ticket! Thanks for helping a newbie :)